# Specifying what data to scrape - Jsoup + Android Studio

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, jsoup

I am using JSoup to scrape data and display in on my phone using android studio. I have code that will scrape all the `<td>` tags however i am not trying to scrape them all, just certain ones in a certain order.

```
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
<table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
<col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
```

Also when it displays on my phone the `<td>` is being displayed and I don't want them to. I don't want to scrape any of the `<td>` tags from the html above

```
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:00</font></td>
    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:15</font></td>
    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:30</font></td>
    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:45</font></td>
```

Above and below is the HTML I want to scrape.

```
<tr >
    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" rowspan='1' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#FFFFFF'>Mon</font></td>
    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='12' rowspan='1' >

<table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
  <col align='left' />
<tr>
  <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Sounds</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
  <col align='left' />
  <col align='right' />
<tr>
  <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>P0000</font></td>
  <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>P.Man</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want it to display is "Mon" then "9:00" then "Sounds" then "P0000" and then "P.Man.

This is the code I have atm. Any one any clues? read the documentation.

```
 Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
                for (Element td : tableElements) {
                    buffer.append("TT [" + td + "] \r\n");
                    Log.d("JSwA", "TT [" + td + "]");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please post the link you are fetching with Jsoup?

Comment: https://timetablesdundalk.wordpress.com/15-2/    , i needed the html online so i could scrape it , it looks terrible visually

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS selector:

```
#post-15 > div > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table:not(:last-of-type)
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/%7E0XRbNDtizzjDAMvOHoeSNL8Q8BQ)

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String text = doc.select("#post-15 > div > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table:not(:last-of-type)").text();
// text should contain "Sounds P0000 P.Man"
```

The above code line tells Jsoup to find all the tables, except the last one ,containing the desired texts.

Comment: thanks man , and thanks for the sample code its a great help, any idea on how to print "mon" and "9:00"?

Comment: @DylanB where do you want to print it?

Comment: i want "Mon" above "9:00" which is above "Sounds P0000 P.Man"